# Query for DeFi/ETH/BSC wallets, transactions, balances

Tags: nodejs, bsc

I'm looking for a way to monitor wallet balances or otherwise somehow query the mainnet for ETH or BSC (or a DeFi contract on either network), but I feel like I "don't know what I don't know" and I can't seem to find the right combination of words to search for this. I'm using NodeJS right now, but can be flexible if need be.

Apologies for the vagueness and if this makes a poor question, but blockchain development is so alien to me - I don't know what libraries are out there or how I use them, and all I want to do is build an API around what *seems* should be simple functions. I'm looking at ethereumjs, ethereumex, and eth_contract... am I going down the wrong path? Is there a link to *anything* that can nudge me in the right direction to using these packages? There's precious little documentation and it's all very unapproachable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NodeJS, you should have a look at web3js:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/

It has a function (among many others) called `getBalance`: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getbalance

You may start from there. I don't know how to be more specific as you do not specify what you mean by "monitor balance".

Comment: Do you know how to get the staked balance on DEFI?